# How do I get the image name form the Codeigniter upload controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

For example if I upload the file foo.png how can I get the string "foo.png" in the upload controller?

The controller code is:

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function do_upload($folder)
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './userdata/'. $folder . '/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            echo "<p>File sucesfully uploaded</p>";

            $filename = // How do I get the filename here

        }
    }
}
?>
```

How can I set `$filename` to the filename of the uploaded file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext'];
```

should do the trick

e.g. you upload your image

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('upload_data')) {
$data = $this->upload->data();
echo $data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [official CI manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html):

```
$this->upload->data()
This is a helper function that returns an array containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded. Here is the array prototype:
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

So in your case the `$data` variable that holds the result of the `$this->upload->data()` function should contain all the info that you need about the file you have uploaded.

And specifically `$data['upload_data']['file_name']` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
echo $data['file_name'];
```